# No jQuery working in IE Versions 6 - 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I seem to have a problem where my jQuery functions don't seem to be working in all IE versions, however the functions seem to work fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

It doesn't even work in IE 11 / Windows 10.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks for your help.

```
(function($) {
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {

     (function(){
        if (!/portfolio-item/.test(window.location.href)) return;

        var i;

        var bigwrap = document.querySelector('.page-header .portfolio-entry-img').parentNode;
        var bigimages = {};

        var products = document.querySelectorAll('.product-thumbnail-wrap img');
        var title = document.querySelector('.product-title');
        var code  = document.querySelector('.product-code');

        var trays_tmp = document.querySelectorAll('.tray-reference [data-tray]');
        var trays = {};

        var wraps_tmp = document.querySelectorAll('.tray-wrap');
        var wraps = {};

        var active = {};
        active.bigimage = bigwrap.firstElementChild;
        if(active.bigimage) bigimages[active.bigimage.src] = active.bigimage;

        for(i in Object.keys(trays_tmp)) {
            if (trays_tmp.hasOwnProperty(i)) { 
                trays[trays_tmp[i].dataset.tray] = trays_tmp[i];
                if(/tray-active/.test(trays_tmp[i].className)) active.tray = trays_tmp[i].dataset.tray;
            }
        }

        for(i in Object.keys(wraps_tmp)) {
            if (wraps_tmp.hasOwnProperty(i)) { 
                var table = wraps_tmp[i].dataset.table;
                wraps[table] = wraps_tmp[i];
                if(wraps_tmp[i].style.display === '') active.wrap = wraps_tmp[i];
            }
        }

        for (i in Object.keys(products)) {
            if (products.hasOwnProperty(i)) { 
                if (/product-thumb-active/.test(products[i].className)) active.product = products[i];

                if (products[i].dataset.big && !bigwrap.querySelector('[src="' + products[i].dataset.big + '"]') && active.bigimage) {
                    var bigimg = active.bigimage.cloneNode();
                    bigimg.src = products[i].dataset.big;
                    bigimg.style.display = 'none';
                    bigwrap.appendChild(bigimg);
                    bigimages[products[i].dataset.big] = bigimg;
                }

                products[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    if (active.product) active.product.className = active.product.className.replace(/\s*product-thumb-active/, '');
                    this.className += ' product-thumb-active';
                    active.product = this;

                    if (active.tray) trays[active.tray].className = trays[active.tray].className.replace(/\s*tray-active/, '');
                    active.tray = this.dataset.tray;
                    if (active.tray){
                        if (!trays[active.tray]) active.tray = undefined;
                        else trays[active.tray].className += ' tray-active';
                    }

                    console.log(active.tray, trays[active.tray]);

                    if ((active.tray && active.wrap !== active.tray[0]) || !active.tray) {
                        if (active.wrap)  active.wrap.style.display = 'none';
                        if (!active.tray) active.wrap = wraps.None;
                        else active.wrap = wraps[active.tray[0]];
                        if (!active.wrap) active.wrap = wraps.None;
                        active.wrap.style.display = '';
                    } 

                    title.textContent = this.getAttribute('title');
                    code.textContent  = this.getAttribute('code');

                    if (active.bigimage) active.bigimage.style.display = 'none';
                    active.bigimage = bigimages[this.dataset.big];
                    $(active.bigimage).fadeIn('fast');
                });
            }
        }
    })();

    $(".nav-toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".overlay-boxify").toggleClass("open");
        $("#site-navigation-wrap").toggleClass("menuActive");
        $(".fixed-logo").toggleClass("logoActive");
        $("#site-social-wrap").toggleClass("socialActive");
    });

    $(".overlay ul li a").click(function() {
        $(".nav-toggle").toggleClass("active");
        $(".overlay-boxify").toggleClass("open");
        $("#site-navigation-wrap").toggleClass("menuActive");
        $(".fixed-logo").toggleClass("logoActive");
    });

    $(".overlay").click(function() {
        $(".nav-toggle").toggleClass("active");
        $(".overlay-boxify").toggleClass("open");
        $("#site-navigation-wrap").toggleClass("menuActive");
        $(".fixed-logo").toggleClass("logoActive");
    });

    $('.single-question').click(function() {
        $('.tray-reference').toggle();
    });

    /***************** Header BG Scroll ******************/
    var pastWaypoint = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 580 && !pastWaypoint) {
            $('.fixed-logo').show();
            $(".fixed-header").addClass("hasBg header-sml");
            $("#site-navigation-wrap").show();
            console.log('d');
            pastWaypoint = true;
        } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 580 && pastWaypoint) {
            $('.fixed-logo').hide();
            console.log('f');
            $(".fixed-header").removeClass("hasBg header-sml");
            pastWaypoint = false;
        }
    });

    $('.menu-item a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function() {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });

    $("img").bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        return false;
    });

    $("div.desc").hide();

    $("input[name$='requestbrochure']").change(function() {
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#" + this.value).show();
    }).filter(function() {
        return this.checked;
    }).change();

    $(".resource-tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("resource-current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("resource-current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".resource-tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });

    $('.portfolio-dropdown-content').show();

    $('#portfolio-dropdown-menu').click(function() {
        $('.portfolio-dropdown-content').slideToggle("fast");
        $('#portfolio-dropdown-icon').toggleClass("portfolio-dropdown-selected");
    });

    $('.request-brochure-button').click(function() {
        $('.request-brochure-content').slideToggle("fast");
        $('.request-brochure-button').toggleClass("request-brochure-button-active");
    });

    // Main menu superfish
    $('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
        delay: 200,
        animation: {
            opacity: 'show',
            height: 'show'
        },
        speed: 'fast',
        cssArrows: false,
        disableHI: true
    });

    // Mobile Menu
    $('#navigation-toggle').sidr({
        name: 'sidr-main',
        source: '#sidr-close, #site-navigation, #mobile-search',
        side: 'left'
    });

    $('.sidr-class-toggle-sidr-close').click(function() {
        $.sidr('close', 'sidr-main');
        return false;
    });

    // Close the menu on window change
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $.sidr('close', 'sidr-main');
    });

    $("#featuresSlider").flickity({
        cellAlign: "left",
        contain: true,
        prevNextButtons: false
    });

    $("#showcaseSlider").flickity({
        cellAlign: "left",
        contain: true,
        prevNextButtons: false,
        imagesLoaded: true
    });

    $(".youtube-media").on("click", function(e) {
        var t = $(window).width();
        if (t <= 768) {
            return
        }
        $.fancybox({
            href: this.href,
            padding: 4,
            type: "iframe",
            href: this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), "v/")
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("a.single_image").fancybox({
        padding: 4
    });

    $(".nav-toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".overlay-boxify").toggleClass("open")
    });

    $(".overlay ul li a").click(function() {
        $(".nav-toggle").toggleClass("active");
        $(".overlay-boxify").toggleClass("open")
    });

    $(".overlay").click(function() {
        $(".nav-toggle").toggleClass("active");
        $(".overlay-boxify").toggleClass("open")
    });

    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 125
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}); // End doc ready

$(window).load(function() {
    // Homepage FlexSlider
    $('#homepage-slider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        slideshow: true,
        smoothHeight: true,
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: true,
        prevText: '<span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>',
        nextText: '<span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>',
        controlsContainer: ".flexslider-container"
    });

    // Post FlexSlider
    $('div.post-slider').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        slideshow: true,
        smoothHeight: true,
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: true,
        prevText: '<span class="fa fa-angle-left"></span>',
        nextText: '<span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span>',
        controlsContainer: ".flexslider-container"
    });
}); // End on window load
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you try `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {alert('no jquery');}`
And could you tell which version of jQuery you're using? 2.x doesn't work on IE 9 or lower as far as I know

Comment: Where abouts? @PeterS

Comment: Anywhere in your code, edit: from the jQuery doc `jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.`, in your IE 11, is JavaScript enabled?

Comment: @PeterS SORRY doesn't work. What does this do? edit: I'm using jQuery v1.11.3

Comment: @PeterS - it does seem to work in Windows XP / IE8

Comment: It should give you a popup window, that says 'no jquery' if jQuery was unavailable on your browser.

Comment: @PeterS There was no popup window. I have been using a browser testing website called SauceLabs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running from a file on your local machine (not an http or https URL)? IE will disable JavaScript on file:// by default. Usually there's an option at the bottom of the page to enable it.

Comment: It's running on a http URL.